# Comment on vimeo video using API (python)

Tags: python, api, vimeo

I'm trying to comment on some video that is on Vimeo using their API, this is my code :

```
import vimeo
client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
api details…)
client.post('https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{ID}/comments')
```

I recived an http message 400 the comment is missing, but where i need to put my comment ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation surrounding `upload_texttrack`? Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion this is how you would leave a *comment*, when the text track is around chapters/subtitles/closed captions specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
client.post(
    'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{ID}/comments',
    data={
        "text": "this is the comment"
    }
)
```

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#create_comment_reply